# Ruby form_for.text_field and javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby, form-for

I use this codeblock to generate a formular with two fields:

```
<%= form_for @micropost do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :content, :onKeyUp => "countCharactersLeft(document.forms[0].elements[2],document.forms[0].elements[3],140)" %><br />
  <input readonly type="text" name="charsLeft" size="3" maxlength="3" value="140">
<% end %>
```

I want to count the number of chars in the first textarea. I use a JavaScript function for that.
To get the function working, I pass the fieldToCount and the field to display the result in with the document.forms[0].elements[2] hardcoded.
 But what I want is to get that dynamically. Is there a way to get the id from the f.text_area to pass into the generation of the javascript call?

Answer (score 0):

To find the ID of a HTML element, just look at the generated source code. In your case, it could be `#content` or `#micorpost_content`. It should be possible to specify in the options hash of the arguments of the `text_area` helper method the ID you want to use. Something like this:

```
<%= f.text_area :content, :id => "my_special_id", :onKeyUp => "countCharactersLeft($('#my_special_id',$('#charsLeft'),140)" %>
```